# Running CGI With Perl under Apache Permission Problem

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, cgi

I have the following entry under `apache2.conf` in my Debian box.

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
Options +ExecCGI
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/mychosendir/cgi-bin/

<Directory /var/www/mychosendir/cgi-bin>
Options +ExecCGI -Indexes
allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then I have a perl cgi script stored under these directories and permissions:

```
nvs@somename:/var/www/mychosendir$ ls -lhR 
.:
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 2 nvs nvs 4.0K 2010-04-21 13:42 cgi-bin

./cgi-bin:
total 4.0K
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nvs nvs 90 2010-04-21 13:40 test.cgi
```

However when I tried to access it in the web browser:

```
http://myhost.com/mychosendir/cgi-bin/test.cgi
```

They gave me this error:

```
[Wed Apr 21 15:26:09 2010] [error] [client 150.82.219.158] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/var/www/mychosendir/cgi-bin/test.cgi' failed
[Wed Apr 21 15:26:09 2010] [error] [client 150.82.219.158] Premature end of script headers: test.cgi
```

What's wrong with it?

**Update**:

I also have the following entry in my `apache2.conf`:

```
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

And the content of `test.cgi` is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "Hello, world!\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a <Directory> section for the cgi-bin directory.  And make sure "allow from all" is in it.

```
<Directory /var/www/mychosendir/cgi-bin>
    Options +ExecCGI -Indexes
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Also...your ScriptAlias is for /cgi-bin/.  Your URL is /mychosendir/cgi-bin.  Unless you have some rewrite magic going on, your url should probably be http://my.host.com/cgi-bin/test.cgi , or you'll need to change your ScriptAlias line to look like

```
ScriptAlias /mychosendir/cgi-bin/ /var/www/mychosendir/cgi-bin
```

The error you posted in your update, sounds like you don't have a #! line at the beginning of your script.  You'll need one, and it should look like

```
#!/path/to/your/perl
```

Comment: @cHao: Sorry I don't get it. As I pointed out in OP I already have `cgi-bin` directory with the right permisson (a+x).

Comment: The directory is there, but unless you have a section in the config file that grants access to it, Apache won't let you see it.

Comment: @cHao: Thanks but how can I change the config to grant access?

Comment: Updated my answer.  Reread.  :)

Comment: I modified the Script alias to `ScriptAlias /var/www/mychosendir/cgi-bin/ /var/www/mychosendir/cgi-bin/` and add the `<Directory>` section exactly like yours. But now it give internal server error instead. 

And BTW, I do really want my url to be `http://myhost.com/mychosendir/cgi-bin/test.cgi` instead of removing the `mychosendir`.

Comment: The first thing in the ScriptAlias directive is the url you want to refer to that directory.  So you'll probably want to get rid of the first /var/www in your ScriptAlias line.

Comment: You mean like this: `ScriptAlias  /mychosendir/cgi-bin/ /cgi-bin/` . Sorry please be patient with me.

Comment: I mean like this: ScriptAlias /mychosendir/cgi-bin/ /var/www/mychosendir/cgi-bin/

Comment: Still internal error. BTW the perl code already contained the right header. See my update.

Comment: I see it.  I'm running the same code on one of my servers right now, so IF your perl is at /usr/bin/perl, then the script should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the Apache user/group has read and execute access for the given files? Usually this user is called httpd or www-data.

Comment: How do I check and enable that?

Comment: First find out as which user Apache is running. This can be done by checking your `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf` - look for the User and Group settings. Next, `ls -al /var/www/mychosendir/cgi-bin` to see the permissions and file owner. The user under which Apache is running must have access to these files. They should also contain the execute bit.

Answer (score 0):

"Premature end of script headers" means that the CGI script is not printing out the correct HTTP header. It needs to print out at least

```
Content-Type: text/html;
```

Also, you have

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/mychosendir/cgi-bin/
```

and yet you are asking for

```
http://myhost.com/mychosendir/cgi-bin/test.cgi
```

That should be

```
http://myhost.com/cgi-bin/test.cgi
```

or say

```
ScriptAlias /mychosendir/cgi-bin/ /var/www/mychosendir/cgi-bin/
```

Comment: It does have. See my update on the test.cgi code.

Comment: I really want it to be accessed here: `http://myhost.com/mychosendir/cgi-bin/test.cgi`. Then how should I modify the ScriptAlias?
I also tried this `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /mychosendir/cgi-bin/` but internal server error.

Comment: You are too dependent on other people to solve all your problems.